# How to remove focus, background-color and hover from Pagination component antd?

Tags: pagination, antd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KA86.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZarE.png)

Hello everyone! How to remove focus, background-color and hover from Pagination component antd? I try to different options but i can't find solution. I will be grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

I decided the problem. We need add classname in Pagination component for example:  and in css (i use scss) we need to apply to the li tag: .pagination {li {border: 1px solid #D9DADA;}}